# write_clip() doesn't work when R Shiny app running on a server

Tags: r, shiny, server

It's really odd because when I run the app on my local instance, it does work. But when I try to run it from the server app nothing would happen. Do I need to use a library specifically for servers and not clipper? its really confusing.

To avoid typing the whole thing, I basically create the DF and then I do
`write_clip(DF)` which should send the DF to my clipboard.

Again, in my local copy it works just fine, but when I hook the app into the server and click the button who runs the fuction, nothing happens.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `write_clip` uses the system clipboard which happens to work when you run shiny server on the same machine (locally). For remote (client-side) functionality, in contrast, these might be helpful: https://github.com/sbihorel/rclipboard/ , https://github.com/deepanshu88/shinyCopy2clipboard